# How to update a Chart

Tags: vb.net

I've just finished developing a piece of code where I am able to create a `Chart` and query from my database. Here I insert values from the database and it will show to the user.

I will post here the code that I've done to create a chart:

```
Public Sub BuildChart()
    Try
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "........."
        Dim sqlStatis As String = "SELECT Top 5 Filename, Filesize FROM infofile"
        Dim Chart1 As New Chart()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatis, SQLCon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "infofile")

        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
        Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()
        Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

        ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1"
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
        Legend1.Name = "Legend1"
        Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)
        Chart1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Chart1.Name = "Chart1"
        Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        Series1.Legend = "Legend1"
        Series1.Name = "Tamanho do ficheiro"
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1)
        Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 300)
        Chart1.TabIndex = 0
        Chart1.Text = "Chart1"

        Chart1.Series("Tamanho do ficheiro").XValueMember = "Filename"
        Chart1.Series("Tamanho do ficheiro").YValueMembers = "Filesize"

        Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("infofile")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

As you can see I've created a method which will be called in the form and the info will be shown there. Outside of everything I declared a variable `Dim Chart1 As New Chart()`. Now I want to create a method which allows me with a timer to update automatically the chart. So I should create another method called `UpdateChart` where I could insert there this:

```
Timer1.Interval = 3000
Timer1.Start()
```

But now I have no idea what should I use to update it every 3 secs or 3000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Load` you want to call the `BuildChart` method and start the timer:

```
Private Sub frmTest_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    BuildChart()

    With Timer1
        .Enabled = True
        .Interval = 3000
        .Start()
    End With

End Sub
```

For `BuildChart` you only need to create the chart itself and not bind the data.

```
Public Sub BuildChart()
    Try
        Dim Chart1 As New Chart()

        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
        Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()
        Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

        ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1"
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
        Legend1.Name = "Legend1"
        Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)
        Chart1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Chart1.Name = "Chart1"
        Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        Series1.Legend = "Legend1"
        Series1.Name = "Tamanho do ficheiro"
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1)
        Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 300)
        Chart1.TabIndex = 0
        Chart1.Text = "Chart1"

        Chart1.Series("Tamanho do ficheiro").XValueMember = "Filename"
        Chart1.Series("Tamanho do ficheiro").YValueMembers = "Filesize"

     Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

We then want `UpdateChart` to be called from the `Timer.Tick` event.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    UpdateChart()

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateChart()

    Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    Chart1.DataSource = ""

    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "............."
    Dim sqlStatis As String = "SELECT Top 5 Filename, Filesize FROM infofile"

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatis, SQLCon)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "infofile")

    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("infofile")    
End Sub
```

Be aware though that this will create a lot of hits to your database.